# Terminology of tensorial and vectorial notation

Tags: vectors, terminology, tensors

I want to make sure whether the terminology that I use is correct or not and also whether its the well known and used normally.

Index notation:

$$T_{ij} ~~,~~ v_j$$

$$T_{ij}v_j$$

Symbolic notation:

$$\mathbb{T} ~,~ \vec{v}$$

$$\mathbb{T} \cdot \vec{v}$$